# Python Class member access

Tags: python, list, operator-overloading, subclass

I am new to python and trying to learn it. Can someone please help me with a simple question I have. I am creating a object as follows:

```
 def myList(list):

    def __repr__(self):
    return list.__repr__(self)
```

So essentially just a list. But then immediately after taking in the input list I want to double its value. i.e.

when I use

```
 t = myList([1, 2, 3])
 print(t)
```

it should output  `[2, 4 ,6]`

Now I know how to double each element of a list for instance I can use

```
 l = [x * 2 for x in l]
```

but I am not sure how to access the member of myList object immediately after creation and double them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `__init__` to perform the transformation of the input before passing it up to `list`'s `__init__`, e.g. with a list comprehension or generator expression:

```
class myList(list):
    def __init__(self, it=()):
        super().__init__([x * 2 for x in it])

    def __repr__(self):
        return list.__repr__(self)
```

The generator expression version would be `super().__init__(x * 2 for x in it)`; it avoids a potentially large temporary `list`, but it's usually going to be a titch slower.

Side-note: You don't need to override `__repr__` at all here; you inherit it from `list` automatically, so you may as well just omit the definition entirely. Overriding it only makes sense if you want to *display* doubled, but *store* the original values, in which case you want:

```
class myList(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr([x * 2 for x in self])
```

**Edit**: Because the OP requested a way to initialize `myList`, then double the values, you can call `list`'s initializer immediately, then have the doubling occur on `myList` afterwards. `myList` still isn't fully initialized until `__init__` returns, and it's going to be slower, but this separates the underlying `list` initialization from the doubling:

```
class myList(list):
    def __init__(self, it=()):
        super().__init__(it)  # Perform list initialization with original values
        # Cycle through values and double each one
        for i, x in enumerate(self):
            self[i] = x * 2
```

Comment: Thanks very much. So essentially behind the scene these are steps happening when i  call myList(some list)  : 1> doubling happens with "some list" 2> then myList gets called with "double of some list".  Just out of curiosity is there an alternative way  where first instantiate myList and then double the member variable ?

Comment: @user1612986: This is making a temporary `list` from the argument with doubled values, then passing it to `list`s initializer, so `myList` has the doubled value from the start. The only other way to do this such that the returned `myList` is already doubled is to initialize normally, then double in place, which is going to be slower and uglier. I'll edit in an example, but I don't recommend it.